# Laravel split query

Tags: laravel

I am having a problem with splitting queries. I have done this a number of times and never had this problem.

When I do it I am getting an object Builder, very big, and not the response to my query. I join a print screen of the beginning of the return. I have not found no help regrading this issue.[image]

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What do you mean by splitting queries? What are you returning (dumping) here? What is the result you want?

Comment: You should add `->get()` or `->first()` to get a result instead of the `Builder`

Answer (score 2):

Once you done querying do a [get()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-get) to return a collection object or [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-first) to return a `model object`. What you have is a [builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses). This could occur like this.

```
$builder = Model::where('user_id', $user_id); // returns a builder
$collection = Model::where('user_id', $user_id)->get(); // returns a collection object
$model = Model::where('user_id', $user_id)->first(); // returns an object
```